# how do i by pass google recovery on HTC 526?

Tags: htc

a Friend gave mea HTC 526 but they hard reset an the phone is asking for me to give the Gmail account that's was set with the phone 
 an I nor  my friend don't know it so how can I skip this an set it up with my email /

Answer (score 0):

Boot the phone into **recovery mode** by using the buttons on the phone.

The way you do this depends on the phone, but with your *HTC 526*, [this link](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.htc.com/in/support/htc-desire-526g-plus-dual-sim/howto/593089.html&ved=0ahUKEwit9Lv3loTUAhULDsAKHSJnAE0QFggfMAE&usg=AFQjCNGNpPUUWcv1m9R53ublnShPvq4fmA&sig2=ngj0ttWVgabK_GJ0P_D-6A) shows that you have to hold down the **POWER** and **VOLUME UP** keys until it gets to recovery mode.

Once in recovery mode, use the *volume* and *power* keys to navigate through the menu. Select the option to completely wipe the data on the phone.

**Please note: *This will erase ALL of the data on the phone***

Once this is done, reboot the phone and you should be able to use the phone without any problems.